# Jquery селекторы | как изменить значение $(this) элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Суть проблемы заключается в том как мне выбрать селектор данного комментария и изменить его содержимое, так как комментариев много

Мой скрипт:

```
$(document).on('click', "#like", function(e){
        console.log("Click like")

        e.preventDefault()
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
        var like = $(this).text()

        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        data = {
            id : id,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken
        }
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            data : data,
            url : "{% url 'comment-like' video.slug %}",
            success : function(data){
                if(data['like'] == 'ok') {
                    console.log("Like now")
                    console.log(like)
                    like++
                    console.log(like)
                    $(this).innerHTML = like
                }
                if(data['like'] == 'no') {
                    console.log("You voted")
                    console.log(like)
                    like++
                    console.log(like)
                    $(this).innerHTML = like
                }
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    })
```

Блок с комментариями которые обрабатывает скрипт:

```
<div class="comments">
<p>Комментарии:</p>
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comment">
    {{comment.nickname}} | {{comment.timestamp}} 
    {% if comment.is_child %}
    <div style="background-color: black; width: 300px;">
        <p>Ответ: {{comment.parent.nickname}}</p>
        <p>Комментарий: "{{comment.parent.text}}"</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{comment.text}}</p> 
    <p><a href="#" id="like" data-id="{{comment.id}}"><i class="far fa-heart"></i>{{comment.get_comment_likes}}</a></p>
    <button style="background-color: black;" class="reply" data-id="{{comment.id}}" data-parent={{comment.get_parent}}>Ответить</button>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="comment-form" id="form-{{comment.id}}" style="display:none;">
        <textarea type="text" name="comment-text">
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn submit-reply" data-id="{{comment.id}}" data-submit-reply="{{comment.get_parent}}" value="Отправить"/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'create-comment' video.slug %}" method="POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment_form.as_table }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Отправить"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Конкретно не работает вот эта строчка:

```
$(this).innerHTML = like
```

Comment: Косяк на косяке. на странице не может быть 2 объектов с одним `id=like`. У вас же их по количеству комментариев. Используйте класс вместо id. У jquery объектов нет свойства `innerHTML` зато есть метод `html(val)`

Comment: Как а как в итоге изменить значение выбранного комментария?

Comment: Я добавил классы вместо id, сделал $(this).text(like) но это не сработало

Comment: контекст потерян потому-что. сохраните `_this = $(this)` перед аяксом и его потом используйте `_this.html(like)`.

Comment: Теперь ясно как переменная `var like = $(this).text()` смогла получить содержимое тега, а в success `$(this).text(like)` не сработал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал селектор по атрибуту *data-id* передал переменную `var id = $(this).attr('data-id')`:

```
$("a[data-id=" + id + "] span").text(like)
```